# Redefinir a função alert

Tags: javascript

Usamos `alert(text)` para dar um alert na janela, existe uma forma de redefinir essa funçao para ao invez de exibir essa janela de padrao ela exiba uma personalizada feita em HTML mas sem perder sua real funçao, seria apenas uma troca do "design" da caixa de dialogo sem perder sua real funcionalidade.

De acordo com respostas eu consigo até me orientar, mas como programar a parte que retorna o OK/CANCEL/NO

Tipo, esta minha funçao:

```
window.safeConfirm = function(params, callback) {
    if (typeof params === 'string') {
        params = {
            message: params
        };
    }
    var result = false;
    try {
        result = confirm(params.message);
    } catch (e) {
        result = true;
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        callback(result);
    }, 10);
};
```

Ela serve para dar um alert em forma de dialogo "sim/nao" e executar uma função de acordo com a resposta do usuário, seu uso seria algo como:

```
safeConfirm({
    type: 'ERROR_1',
    message: 'lalalala'
}, function() {
    window.location.reload();
});
```

se eu redefinir a funçao como nas respostas essa funçao nao funcionaria e eu perderia o que eu quero que é a funcionalidade do alert com o alert sendo feito em HTML.. Entao afinal, como fazer?

Answer (score 4):

Você pode simplesmente substituí-la:

```js
/**
 * Ao invés de exibir uma janela de alerta,
 * a mensagem será exibida no console - CTRL + SHIFT + K.
 */
window.alert = function(msg){
  // faz algo
  console.log(msg);  
}

alert("StackOverflowPT");
```

Se quiser "fazer algo" e ainda assim manter o comportamento do `alert`, pode fazer dessa forma:

```js
/**
 * Exibe a mensagem no console mas ainda assim
 * mantém o comportamento do 'alert'.
 */
var _alert = window.alert;

window.alert = function(msg) {
  // faz algo
  console.log(msg);
  return _alert.apply(this, arguments);
};

alert("StackOverflowPT");
```

Comment: Renan, este `this` se refere à `_alert` e `arguments` se refere à `msg`? Então na prática, é como se estivesse fazendo algo do tipo: `var a = function(msg) { console.log(msg); return alert(msg); };`, só que mantendo o nome `alert` para a função? Só pra garantir! :P

Comment: Sim eu queria manter a funçao alert mas nao ela na sua totalidade (exibindo a janela...) veja minha pergunta atualizada por favor?

Comment: @renan realmente eu me embaralhei.. Vou ter que recorrer a um plugin

Answer (score 3):

Se pretendes estilizar a janela nativa que aparece para quando é pedido *input* ao utilizador, ou a janela de alerta do sistema isso não é posível.

Podes reescrever a função `alert` [como o @renan sugeriu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/66708/129) mas não a janela nativa do Browser para ações/comportamentos *standard*. **Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/rsLavcm5/**

Isso seria aliás uma quebra de segurança grande e facilmente poderia prejudicar o utilizador se fosse mal usada.

Comment: Pode fornecer um exemplo de quebra de segurança? Eu certamente concordo - talvez por inércia ou talvez pelo fato de preservar a base da linguagem e evitar problemas no código - mas não penso em nada. Segurança não é meu forte.

Comment: @José caso fosse possível alterar os alertas nativos do browser seria possivel por exemplo ignorar todos os alertas que o Browser der, assim como manipular todas os pedidos de "concordo / não concordo" que o browser pergunta em relação a cookies, cartão de crédito, etc...

Comment: Sergio eu adaptei minha pergunta e a detalhei.

Comment: @user3163662 o que queres é substituir a janela nativa para confirmações do tipo `OK`/ `Cancel`?

Comment: @Sergio seria tanto para esta tanto para apenas um alert normal..

Comment: @user3163662 o que é nativo do Browser não podes substituir. Está protegido pelo Browser.

Comment: @Sergio mas nao tem como fazer um script que trabalhe de forma semelhante?

Comment: @user3163662 não.

Comment: @Sergio tem que ter uai JS faz tanta coisa por que nao uma que funcione como o alert.. Mas Obrigado! Vou pensar em algo e respondo a pergunta se necessário.

Answer (score 2):

As funções [`alert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert), [`prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) e [`confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Windowconfirm), nativas dos browsers, possuem um comportamento que é impossível de reproduzir: elas bloqueiam o processamento de qualquer código JavaScript posterior até que sejam dispensadas. É por isso que `prompt` e `confirm` permitem capturar diretamente um valor de retorno, como neste exemplo:

```
var valorDigitado = prompt('Digite um valor');
```

Qualquer substituto customizado (mesmo que seja feito usando um moderno [HTML5 `<dialog>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog)) será assíncrono e vai depender de callbacks, como no seu exemplo e no [exemplo do Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/66709), e portanto não poderia substituir diretamente uma chamada a `prompt` ou `confirm`, que são funções síncronas, que retornam um valor.