# Usar custom alert em javascript

Tags: javascript, alert

Estou tentando usar algo que não seja o alerta padrão do javascript e aparentemente trocar a sintaxe não funciona. 
Por exemplo, esse código funciona.

```
$mysqlInsert = mysqli_query($conexao,$sqlInsert);
            if (!mysqlInsert) {
                die('Error: ' . mysqli_error()); 
            }
            else {
                echo '<script>window.alert("Produto adicionado com sucesso!");
                        window.location.href="main.php";</script>';
                }
}
```

Mas esse não (a biblioteca está sendo chamada corretamente):

```
$mysqlInsert = mysqli_query($conexao,$sqlInsert);
            if (!mysqlInsert) {
                die('Error: ' . mysqli_error()); 
            }
            else {
                echo '<script>swal("Produto adicionado com sucesso!");
                        window.location.href="main.php";</script>';
                }
}
```

Pude perceber que só quando uso onclick, em um botão por exemplo, que consigo chamar o alert customizado. Alguém sabe me explicar porque?

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/66706/129

Comment: Você conseguiu resolver consultando o link postado por @Sergio?

Comment: Não, tive que fazer por javascript mesmo